# Spring Integration - url-variable not working in http:outbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In order to send http request to dynamic urls based on message headers...

I am trying to set the url value from Message header as follows:

```
 <int-http:outbound-gateway id="httpOutboundGateway" request-channel="fromMyQueue" 
    url="{outboundGatewayUrl}" reply-channel="nullChannel" 
    http-method="POST" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8">
<int-http:uri-variable name="outboundGatewayUrl" expression="headers['X-CUSTOM-HTTP-REQUEST-URL']" />
```

But this is not working. 
Apparently `{outboundGatewayUrl}` value is not being replaced at all.
This works if i replace the `{outboundGatewayUrl}` with actual URL.

**Error Message:**

```
Caused by:
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [{outboundGatewayUrl}]...

Caused by:<br> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:109)
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like header X-CUSTOM-HTTP-REQUEST-URL doesn't exist in the message.

You will get that error (URI is not absolute) if the expression returns null (i.e. if the header doesn't exist).

I just ran a test and it worked fine for me with a proper header; if you believe the header is correct, you should break down the problem; for example by using a literal expression first...

```
<int-http:uri-variable name="outboundGatewayUrl" expression="'http://foo/bar'" />
```

The error message is, perhaps somewhat misleading:

```
Caused by:
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed    for URI [{outboundGatewayUrl}]...
```

because it implies the url wasn't expanded. The problem is the expansion is done inside the RestTemplate and the adapter doesn't have access to it.

Comment: Gary> I tried what you suggested - yes using literal expression worked fine. I am actually reading message from a Queue (Rabbit MQ) and in this next step sending out http request to a URL present in header of message. So i do put a header there on Message (in Rabbit MQ)- so i am wondering if those headers are not showing up in Messages in Spring?

Comment: If you turn on debug logging, you can see the headers.

Comment: For messages coming from amqp, you will need to add a 'mapped-request-headers' attribute to the inbound adapter. Without it, and DEBUG logging, you will see that custom headers are NOT mapped by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `$` sign before your `{outboundGatewayUrl}` and consequently it is not being expanded by SEL. This is also suggested in the error message.

Comment: DaveRlz> Adding $ sign did not help, also i have not seen examples which use $ sign. But yes... SEL is not evaluating the expression at all... but why. Am i missing any libraries or schema name entries somewhere

Comment: Did adding the dollar sign change the message, is it still displaying the unexpanded value or is it now empty?

Comment: No, these URI placeholders are replaced dynamically at runtime, the ${} syntax is for placeholders resolved at context initialization time.